# How to start the numbering of figures at a specific digit in ConTeXt

Tags: tex

How can I start the numbering of figures at a specific digit in ConTeXt.

Minimal example:

```
\setuppapersize[A6]
\setupexternalfigures[location=default]

\setupcaptions[way=bytext] 

\placefigure
    {Cow}
    {\externalfigure[cow][width=2cm]}

\placefigure
    {Another Cow}
    {\externalfigure[cow][width=2cm]}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\setuppapersize[A6]
\setupexternalfigures[location=default]

\setupcaptions[way=bytext]

\setnumber[figure][2]

\placefigure
    {Cow}
    {\externalfigure[cow][width=2cm]}

\placefigure
    {Another Cow}
    {\externalfigure[cow][width=2cm]}
```